# How can I prevent my NUnit tests from running in parallel sometimes

Tags: c#, unit-testing, concurrency, locking, nunit

I'm using the NUnit test runner included in Monodevelop. I have 2 tests which must interact with static resources so I need them to run serially rather than parallel. I've tried using something like

```
static string Locker="foo";
[Test]
public void Test1()
{
  lock(Locker)
  {
    //....
  }
}
[Test]
public void Test2()
{
  lock(Locker)
  {
    //....
  }
}
```

This doesn't seem to work though. Is there some other way?

Comment: As a side note, you should never lock on strings.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using this approach when **REALLY** needed (i think it's a bad idea):

```
using System.Threading;
private ManualResetEvent FixtureHandle = new ManualResetEvent(true);
[SetUp]
public void SetUp()
{
    FixtureHandle.WaitOne();
}
[TearDown]
public void TearDown()
{
    FixtureHandle.Set();
}
[Test]
public void Test1()
{
  //only test
}
[Test]
public void Test2()
{
  //only test
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Dont know about Monodevelop but nunit console has [command line argument](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=consoleCommandLine&r=2.4) **/nothread**

It should be something similar in Monodevelop i think

Answer (score 1):

For running tests serially it's best to use the Order attribute:

```
static string Locker="foo";
[Test, Order(1)]
public void Test1()
{
  lock(Locker)
  {
    //....
  }
}
[Test, Order(2)]
public void Test2()
{
  lock(Locker)
  {
    //....
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the static resource directly, extract that into a dependency, and mock it (using [moq](http://code.google.com/p/moq/) or something similar).

That will let you write actual unit tests that isolate the specific piece of code you are trying to test without worrying about external context.

Comment: I came here looking for this answer for integration testing reasons. This would not help in that scenario

Answer (score -3):

You are missing the point of the Unit Testing. The Unit tests must be independent in every way.

This means that the execution order must not influence the Unit Tests results.

Comment: Well, I can make them independent, but it would require my tests to be significantly more complicated

Comment: @marjan perhaps you're missing the point of NUnit!
It isn't exclusively used for unit testing. It's also a useful test runner for integration and system tests, e.g. http://nadimsaker.blogspot.co.uk/2015/05/specflow-how-to-write-selenium.html
And for those tests, while test order shouldn't matter, parallel tests can be problematic, so I think it's a fair question.

Comment: I agree @ben. In fact we are using it for integration tests as well. My point was in case of testing, execution order must not matter. Every single unit/integration test has to be independent for itself.

Comment: @marjan The question didn't relate to execution order (which shouldn't matter), it was about concurrent execution (which does matter for system and integration tests which manipulate shared state).

Comment: @ben for both scenarios it does matter. Execution order, shared state.. - You can write such test, except you are ignoring what the solution architecture is trying to tell you. - Refactor your coupled code base.

Comment: How do you decouple an integration test from a resource? Several separate integration test only databases? Not likely